# How to construct a MySQL query that uses a group by statement to SUM() values, and also includes extra columns that are used in the summed values?

Tags: sql, mysql

How to construct a MySQL query that uses a group by statement to SUM() values, and also includes extra columns that are used in the summed values?

I have a mysql database with one `sales` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_sold` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

And the data looks something like...

```
user      | products_sold | location | day
Bob       | 10            | Mars     | Tuesday
Randy     | 12            | Venus    | Thursday
Bob       | 7             | Venus    | Thursday
```

Note that the intention is for the database to maintain this exact same structure. So I will not be adding a new foreign key table for `user` or anything like that... it will stay simple and flat like above.

What I want to do is construct an SQL query that provides a result displaying:

- The users (Bob, Randy)
- The **total** number of products sold for the specific user
- The total number of products sold for the user on Tuesday
- The total number of products sold for the user on Thursday
  So the result would look like:

```
user      | total_sold | tuesday_total | thursday_total
Bob       | 17         | 10            | 7
Randy     | 12         | 0             | 12
```

I have a SELECT statement that retrieves the first two columns successfully:

```
select user, sum(products_sold) as total_sold from sales
  group by user order by total_sold desc
```

This query retrieves the first two columns I am looking for, like so:

```
user      | total_sold
Bob       | 17        
Randy     | 12
```

So my question is, how do I construct a query that retrieves the second two columns as well?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is a Pivot.

In Mysql you can make use of a boolean expression within a sum, so adding to your existing query for your specific example:

```
select user, 
  sum(products_sold) total_sold ,
  sum((day = 'Tuesday') * products_sold) tuesday_total,
  sum((day = 'Thursday') * products_sold) thursday_total
from sales
group by user 
order by total_sold desc;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jyn-yckG)